# Rails: How to group records that have the same Date (month day year) for a Datetime field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Purchase` model and I want to group all of the records by their `ordered_datetime` field. However, I don't care about the time, I just want to group by the date. So if there are 2 orders ordered on:

1. 5/12/2014 12:00PM
2. 5/12/2014 3:00PM

They should be grouped together even though they happened at different times during the day.

Is there a way to do this? `Purchase.uniq.pluck(:ordered_datetime)` separates the 2 records into 2 groups since their times are different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `DATE` function on the timestamp column:

```
Purchase.group('DATE(ordered_datetime)').count
```

Which returns each date with a purchase count.

You can also sort the dates by adding an order clause:

```
Purchase.group('DATE(ordered_datetime)').order('date_ordered_datetime').count
```

Comment: @Edmund – is this even what you asked for?

Comment: yeh exactly what I wanted. it returns this `{nil=>1706, Thu, 17 Apr 2014=>2, Tue, 22 Apr 2014=>4, Thu, 24 Apr 2014=>4, Wed, 30 Apr 2014=>2, Thu, 01 May 2014=>3, Fri, 02 May 2014=>1, Tue, 06 May 2014=>1} `

Comment: @Edmund, uh, no... it returns an integer.

Comment: @zeantsoi oops yeh I modified it a bit. But it was still what I was looking for with the `DATE(ordered_datetime)` part

Comment: @Edmund, I'm just curious to know how this answer differs from the first answer posted.